# Warping curved rectangle to a regular rectangle

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Edit: Upon further research, I've came across similar questions. I guess the process is not as trivial as using the WarpPerspective() function. [Here](https://answers.opencv.org/question/42819/warpperspective-of-deformed-rectangle/) is a similar question and an answer.

I'm using methods like thresholding and canny to extract a rectangular shape from books. Sometimes the rectangles (contours) are deformed like this (pages are not always flat):

[image]

As you can see the bottom line is not a straight line. I need to warp it into a rectangle to do further analysis of its inside contents.

Normally, I use WarpPerspective() using the 4 points I get from ApproxPolyDP() with a contour like this and it works fine:

[image]

But I can't figure out what to do with a curved rectangle. Here is what I get using the method I use on non-curved rectangles. It's close but not quite what I want:

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to show a [mcve] to reproduce your results? Couldn't you just save the four corner points you receive from `cv::ApproxPolyDP` in a `cv::Rect` structure?